# SaveButton disabled with isValid still disabled after await user.type success

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form, react-admin, vitest

I test my SimpleForm, but even after writing input successfuly, my SaveButton is still disabled (contains className 'Mui-disabled').

npm packages useful here:

- vitest: 0.34.1
- react-hook-form: 7.45.2
- react-admin: 4.11.0
- testing-library/react: 14.0.0
- react: 18.2.0

Toolbar:

```
const SaveCancelDeleteToolbar = (props: SaveCancelDeleteToolbarProps) => {
  const { closeDrawer, handleCancel } = props

  const translate = useTranslate()

  const {
    formState: { isValid },
  } = useFormContext()

  return (
    <Toolbar>
      <SaveButton disabled={!isValid} onClick={closeDrawer} />
      <Button onClick={handleCancel}>{translate('ra.action.cancel')}</Button>
    </Toolbar>
  )
}
```

Form:

```
<SimpleForm mode="all" reValidateMode="onChange" toolbar={toolbar}>
  <TextInput
    data-testid="form.value"
    label="resources.values.fields.value"
    source="value"
    validate={[required(), maxLength(50), noEmptySpace]}
  />
</SimpleForm>
```

To prevent react-hook-form crash on test env, I have to use a wrapper to add `const formMethods = useForm()`

Test file:

```
it('should be able to create element', async () => {

// ValueList contains somewhere the SimpleForm.
const { user, ...utils } = setup(
  <FormContextWrapper resource="vat-rates">
    <ValueList deleted={false} />
  </FormContextWrapper>
)

/* Some code that open my SimpleForm **/

// Check that SaveButton is disabled when pristine
const saveButton = await screen.findByText('ra.action.save')
expect(saveButton.outerHTML.includes('Mui-disabled')).toBe(true)

const divValue = await screen.findByTestId(
        'form.value'
      )
const inputValue = divValue.children[1].children[0]

fireEvent.focus(inputValue )
await user.type(inputValue , '1')
fireEvent.blur(inputValue )

// This expect is successful, my input has been set to '1'.
expect(inputValue.value).toBe('1')

await waitFor(() => {
  const saveButton2 = screen.getByText('ra.action.save')
  // This expect fails. saveButton2 exist.
  // Its outerHTML is the following. In react-admin I saw that in DOM, disabled is always "" so I check with 'Mui-disabled' presence.
  // `<button class="LotsOfClasses Mui-disabled" tabindex="-1" type="submit" disabled="" aria-label="ra.action.save">ra.action.save</button>`
  expect(saveButton2.outerHTML.includes('Mui-disabled')).toBe(false)
})

})
```

For an unknown reason, the SaveCancelDeleteToolbar component is not rerendered on test environment. And so isValid stays false and SaveButton still has 'Mui-disabled' className.

Please help, testing forms is a very important process that cannot be neglected.

Comment: "I have to use a wrapper to add const formMethods = useForm()" This looks very suspicious to me, and could very well be the source of your issue. You should not need to do that, and instead, should focus on fixing your issue with react-hook-form in test mode first. Have a look at this [discussion](https://discord.com/channels/830711057643208724/1083442069101608980/1133766584415043664) from the official React Admin Discord server, it might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @slax57 said, it was the wrapper workaround that was problematic.

For a reason still unknown to me, on test environnement "both the esm and change version of react-hook-form was being loaded".

Solution was to add the following lines to `vite.config.js` file.

```js
resolve: {

    alias: {

      'react-hook-form': require.resolve('react-hook-form'),

    }

  }
```